# cypress `cy.now()` Type 'Promise<any>' has no call signatures

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have such `addQuery`:

```
Cypress.Commands.addQuery('closePopup', (id) => {
const getClosePopup = cy.now('get',`[data-testid="${id}"]`);
    return () => {
      return getClosePopup();
  }
});
```

And fro this i do get such error

```
This expression is not callable.
Not all constituents of type 'Promise<any> | ((subject: any) => any)' are callable.
Type 'Promise<any>' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

ANy hints on this :/?

Comment: It's working fine - what else can you tell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `cy.now('get',[data-testid="${id}"])` does not return a function.

You should add a function wrapper:

```js
Cypress.Commands.addQuery('closePopup', (id) => {
  const getClosePopup = () => cy.now('get',`[data-testid="${id}"]`);
  return () => {
      return getClosePopup();
  }
})
```

or return the expression directly from the query function

```js
Cypress.Commands.addQuery('closePopup', (id) => {
  return () => {
    return cy.now('get',`[data-testid="${id}"]`)
  }
})
```

Really, you just need a jQuery expression

```js
Cypress.Commands.addQuery('closePopup', (id) => {
  return () => {
    return Cypress.$(`[data-testid="${id}"]`)
  }
})
```